# How to show invisible Views in designer?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

So, I have a Layout that is

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

is there a way to force ui designer in intellij idea to display such elements at all times?

Comment: it is not possible afaik (unlike Storyboards in iOS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html) you can use the tools xmlns:

```
tools:visibility="visible"
```

> Android Studio supports a variety of XML attributes in the tools
>   namespace that enable design-time features (such as which layout to
>   show in a fragment) or compile-time behaviors (such as which shrinking
>   mode to apply to your XML resources). When you build your app, the
>   build tools remove these attributes so there is no effect on your APK
>   size or runtime behavior.
>
> To use these attributes, add the tools namespace to the root element
>   of each XML file where you'd like to use them, as shown here:
>
> ```
> <RootTag xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use this `tools:visibility="visible"`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.